# How to use intent params to verify the callers calling onActivityResults() method?

Tags: android

I'm wondering if it is possible to verify the the callers calling onActivityResult() method of  startActivityForResult(); 
Here is the situation: I have two widgets in my home screen for invoking the default camera and video of device. Intent has been used with following params for camera: android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_CAMERA_CAPTURE and video: android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE.
After this i have called the startActivityForResult(intent, 0) for both from their respective onClick() methods. I have one onActivityResult() method and want to perform some task using if else statements. Now i want to know how to bifurcate the calling intents and hence direct them to their respective code section

e.g.

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) 
   {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if(intent.???????){ //here i need some filter which could verify the calling intent.  
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iVCenterLogo);
        imv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
           }
             }
            else {
            //code to perform video stuff
             }     
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

mrana...

Comment: the intent you get is a result intent. it does not contain the params you passed. to differentiate the calls, you need to use the requestCode

Comment: But how to get valuable stuff from requestCode? any idea?

Comment: you call startActivityForResult with a given requestCode, that's the code you get back in onActivityResult. That is used to differentiate the activities you may launch

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
.....
startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE_1);

startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE_N);
.....   



    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case YOUR_REQUEST_CODE_1: {
                .... 
                break;
            }
            ....
            case YOUR_REQUEST_CODE_N: {
                .....
                break;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

But this feature wont work with honeycomb you can check it. Whenever you call other package activities from your application using **startActivityForResult()** method then **onActivityResult()** method would be called immediately with **RESULT_CANCELED**. So dont use this strategy.
Use broadcast when camera captures picture or take video.
If you are calling activities from same package then you can go ahead with differenct **requestCodes**.

Comment: Yeah i'm calling both things camera and video from same activity and that is my application's main activity. Guess i'm safe now :)

Comment: I mean to ask, are you using system camera application?

Comment: then dont use startActivityForResult(). Use broadcast when camera takes picture or video. Please try to read my first comment carefully.You wont be able to send stuff from system camera application because its system application. If you are using startActivityResult() approach your application wont be compatible with honeycomb and latest versions.

Comment: Could you provide any code snippet or link which i could follow.

Comment: u should check the code you have approved with honeycomb(appserv's code) before marking it right answer it is definetly not right. As i have noticed earlier in past.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8629/discussion-between-mrana-and-vishal)

Comment: I dont have much time but pics/videos capture by camera are common content follow this link to resolve your problem by studying [here](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2008/03/observing-content.html)

Comment: Vishal, I think you are right only in one case - if activity launchMode is singleInstance. In other cases startActivityForResult() method then onActivityResult() works as expected

Comment: My only point is startActivityForResult() never work when you are launching other packages/applications in Honeycomb versions.

Comment: I run application on android 3.0, 3.2 - works perfect, if only launchMode NOT singleInstance